# Getting the orientation in windows phone native/xaml app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

To apply orientation support to my game, I have been trying to get the screen orientation via

```
Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayProperties::CurrentOrientation
```

But this throws an immediate exception. I searched on the net what might be the cause of it, but couldnt find any helpful resources. In this link , http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/246733-DisplayProperties-CurrentOrientation-not-supported-in-XAML-app a similar exception is discussed , and as a solution using App.RootFrame.Orientation in c# side is proposed.

But I need to get the orientation in native code. What could you suggest on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Accelerometer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) sensor to get the exact orientation when the device doesn't move much or simply use the `Frame` dimensions.